# Azure Application Insights Analytics Query with Cross Cluster Join

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a cluster receiving telemetry about Page Views, and I have another cluster where I imported some data that will give more insight about those pages, like what feature (business area) they belong to.
The problem is that the Join query does not return any value.

[Query on AppPageViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T93T6.png)

[Query on another cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW9dT.png)

[Query with Cross Cluster Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yczrz.png)

I tried other Join Flavors, but had no success.

I expected to view the AppPAgeViews together with correspondent FeatureId from table k3telemetryformfeatures.

Comment: It will be better for community to paste queries in your question rather than attaching them as links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to invert my query, the native cluster must be selected in context.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data#cross-query-of-your-log-analytics-or-application-insights-workspace-and-the-azure-data-explorer-native-cluster

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).